# Oracle Apex passing item results from a Select list to another Select list on the same page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I have two Select list on a single page and I have a very basic sql in the first Select list that will return the following:

Select List 1

Select
Cause as D , causeid as R from xyz

example results

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 2
d = 3
```

And in the second Select List I would like to only load what the user selects in the the first.
So if the user selects c in the first I only want to load

```
C = 2 i
```

n the second Select List which is the results of the first Select List.

Thanks for any help.

I tired to set the DEFAULt of the second Select List to the First.

```
:SelectList1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the 2nd LoV query is supposed to filter rows based on result of value selected in the 1st Lov. If that's so, that's called *cascading*.

Your example is rather *dummy* (a, b, c, ...). A better example is

- 1st LoV selects continents (let's presume that item name is `P1_CONTINENT`)

  ```
  select name, id
  from continents
  ```
- 2nd LoV selects countries (let's call it `P1_COUNTRY`) on continent selected in the 1st LoV

  ```
  select name, id
  from countries
  where continent_id = :P1_CONTINENT
  ```

  But that's not all - you have to put `P1_CONTINENT` into "Parent item(s)" property in "Cascading list of values" section of `P2_COUNTRY` item.

[image]